# Does the "speed" stat still not affect regular driving speed?

Tags: mario-kart-8

In Mario Kart 7, the "speed" stat only affected your speed when going through boosts. Two different players driving in a straightaway with no boosts would travel at the exact same speed.

Is this still the case in MK8 or do we need to pay more attention to Speed in this game?

Comment: I've never heard of that asserssion before (that speed has no effect in MK7). Do you have a source?

Comment: @Toomai 3 stars on all tracks on all difficulties including mirror, 3000 online rating, and all Nintendo ghosts beaten :)

Comment: Do you have a source we can check for ourselves? Video comparisons would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8#Vehicle_parts), I found this:

> **Speed:** The top speed of the vehicle.

It does not state however if the top speed is reached driving on normal track or going through a boost. But it then says:

> **Acceleration:** The rate of the vehicle it takes to reach its **top speed** from a standing position.

Assuming they tested the acceleration in controlled conditions, boosts would not be involved in finding he acceleration because of how they speed up the kart.

Therefore the top speed of each kart can be reached without boosts, although the kart can reach a greater speed through a boost.

For example:

If you were driving a golf cart at its top speed (say 20 km/h), then a car came up behind you and pushed you up to 40 km/h, giving you a **boost**. The top speed of the kart is still 20, even though it can *go* faster.

The speed stat does effect regular driving speed, regardless of boosts.

Comment: I don't think the wording on a nonofficial public wiki really tells us anything about the question. Likely testing and analysis will be required.